# How to get new the coordinate of a text object after rotation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, text

I have some text tag that is child of g tag. After I rotate text tag, I don't know how to get new coordinates of text object ( such as: new x, new y, width, height).

Is there any way to calculate Ending coordinates of the text objects after rotation ?

If anybody knows please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tex objects don't have  `width` or `height` attributes, so I presume you mean that you want the bounding box of the text object?

You said that your `<text>` object has a parent `<g>` element. So what you can do is call `getBBox()` on the parent group object. That will return the bounds of the text object.  Of course that is as long as it is the only thing inside the group.

```js
var group = document.getElementById("group");
var boundingBox = group.getBBox();
alert("x = " + boundingBox.x + "\n y = " + boundingBox.y + "\n width = " + boundingBox.width + "\n height = " + boundingBox.height);
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <g id="group">
    <text x="0" y="20" transform="rotate(45,0,100)">Some text</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: bounding box is a constant, it doesn't change when you change x or change text-anchor. So I need solutions to calculate new value after change.

Comment: You are mistaken. The bounding box will change if you change either of those attributes.